# pylucene - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'org'

Tags: python, lucene, pylucene

```
# Common imports:
import sys
from os import path, listdir

from org.apache.lucene.document import Document, Field, StringField, TextField
from org.apache.lucene.util import Version
from org.apache.lucene.store import RAMDirectory
from datetime import datetime

# Indexer imports:
from org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous import LimitTokenCountAnalyzer
from org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard import StandardAnalyzer
from org.apache.lucene.index import IndexWriter, IndexWriterConfig
# from org.apache.lucene.store import SimpleFSDirectory

# Retriever imports:
from org.apache.lucene.search import IndexSearcher
from org.apache.lucene.index import DirectoryReader
from org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic import QueryParser

# ---------------------------- global constants ----------------------------- #

BASE_DIR = path.dirname(path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
INPUT_DIR = BASE_DIR + "/input/"
INDEX_DIR = BASE_DIR + "/lucene_index/"
```

I'm trying test pylucene library. I have written this code only for import test. It doesn't work. I get

```
bigissue@vmi995554:~/myluceneproj$  cd /home/bigissue/myluceneproj ; /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python3.10 /home/bigissue/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.16.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 36991 -- /home/bigissue/myluceneproj/hello_lucene.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bigissue/myluceneproj/hello_lucene.py", line 29, in <module>
    from org.apache.lucene.document import Document, Field, StringField, TextField
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'org'
bigissue@vmi995554:~/myluceneproj$
```

I have run `python3.10 -m pip list` and there is "lucene" module. if I import lucene work well but python doesn't recognize org module. Why?

**UPDATE**

I downloaded lucene 9.1 and set environment variable (`/etc/environment`):

`CLASSPATH=".:/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk-amd64/lib:/home/bigissue/all_lucene/lucene-9.4.1/modules:/home/bigissue/all_lucene/lucene-9.1.0/modules" export CLASSPATH`

I downloaded pylucene-9.1.0 and I have installed it
first jcc

```
bigissue@vmi995554:~/all_lucene/pylucene-9.1.0$ pwd
/home/bigissue/all_lucene/pylucene-9.1.0/jcc
bigissue@vmi995554:~/all_lucene/pylucene-9.1.0$python3.10 setup.py build
bigissue@vmi995554:~/all_lucene/pylucene-9.1.0$python3.10 setup.py install
```

I downloaded also ant apache.

then pylucene 9.1
`cd ..`
I have edit Makefile
`vim /home/bigissue/all_lucene/pylucene-9.1.0/Makefile`

```
PREFIX_PYTHON=/usr/bin
ANT=/home/bigissue/all_lucene/apache-ant-1.10.12
PYTHON=$(PREFIX_PYTHON)/python3.10
JCC=$(PYTHON) -m jcc --shared
NUM_FILES=10
```

```
bigissue@vmi995554:~/all_lucene/pylucene-9.1.0: make 
bigissue@vmi995554:~/all_lucene/pylucene-9.1.0: make install
```

if I run python3.10 -m pip install | grep -i "lucene" I see it.

```
bigissue@vmi995554:~/all_lucene/pylucene-9.1.0$ python3.10 -m pip list | grep -i "lucene"
lucene                 9.1.0
```

Now I have imported lucene

```
import sys
from os import path, listdir
from lucene import * 

directory = RAMDirectory()
```

But I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'RAMDirectory' from 'lucene' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/lucene-9.1.0-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/lucene/__init__.py)
```

Comment: If using `from lucene import IndexReader` leads to a new error (based on comments I can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74247605/pylucene-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-org/74247692#comment131085328_74247692)), then there is some other issue. Can you describe more fully how you installed and configured PyLucene, including which versions of software you are using? You can [edit] your question to show this additional information.

Comment: I edited my question adding UPDATE section. Can you help me?

Comment: I just noticed your comment. If you want to ping a specific person in a thread you have to use the `@` symbol with their user name - for example: @zabitstack. Anyway, I have updated my answer for your issue (if it is still an issue).

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't use that kind of imports.
Just import lucene.

*If this doesn't fix your problem, sorry!*

Comment: import lucene but then I get ImportError: cannot import name 'IndexReader' from 'lucene' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/lucene-9.1.0-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/lucene/__init__.py)

Comment: Are you importing it like `from lucene import IndexReader`?

Comment: Are you importing it like from lucene import IndexReader? Yes

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `from lucene import whatever`.

See the [Features documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/features.html), where it states:

> "*The PyLucene API exposes all Java Lucene classes in a flat namespace in the PyLucene module.*"

So, in Java you use `import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;` but in PyLucene you use `from lucene import IndexReader`.

---

**Update**

Regarding the latest error you mentioned in the comments to your question:

> `ImportError: cannot import name 'RAMDirectory' from 'lucene'`

Lucene's `RAMDirectory` has been deprecated for a long time - and was finally [removed from version 9.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-8474) of Lucene.

You can use a different directory implementation.

Recommended: [`MMapDirectory`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/MMapDirectory.html) - but there are other options such as [`ByteBuffersDirectory`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store)

(Just to note, a new error/issue should really be addressed by asking a new question.)

Comment: if I dir(lucene) I find few methods. For example FSDirectory there isn't. I make from lucene import FSDirectory but I get an error. ImportError: cannot import name 'FSDirectory' from 'lucene'